# Uploading apk to aplha channel for first time for testing of inapp android

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

i am trying to uploading apk to test inapp on alpha channel but getting below error.

i am uploading signed apk for first time. so my versionCode 1 versionName "1.0" but still getting same error.my package name "xxx.xxxx.xxx" that is not available in play store.

i need to test inapp before any version of my app available on play store.
 can you give me any suggetion?

[image]

Comment: you are uploading your new apk with different keystore and in the account in which already one apk is uploaded with some other keystore.That is why it is giving error.

Comment: but  i am uploading first time apk

Answer (score 0):

You are uploading apk file signed with the wrong certyficate. All apk's uploaded to Google Play Store should be signed with same release certyficate as previous apk version

Comment: but he is saying he is doing for first time

Comment: no you are not. As the message error says that you are uploading newer version of apk which package name is mobi.playlearn. Maybe you are uploading wrong apk file or to wrong google play app / account. It is saying that you already have version with version code 1

Answer (score 0):

How did you make sure that, current package name is not used by any one else in google playstore (unpublished app maybe).
The package name will be unique, google validates the package name and the apk certificate, this is not matching with the existing one in google.
the best way is change your package name and sign the apk and upload it again.

Comment: This does not qualify for an answer. It's better suited as a comment. If you don't have enough reputation to comment, kindly wait till you earn it.

Comment: enough now ? @prerak

Answer (score 0):

By just doing a simple search on Google i found: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.playlearn - which is not available in my country.

Seems an app with the same package name is already uploaded on PlayStore and available for everyone. You need to change the package name and upload it, or else Google will detect the app is already available and ask you to upload an apk signed with the same signing key.

PS: there is also https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.playlearn.languages so make sure you dont use mobi.playlearn.languages as package name, as its already used.